# NUSOAP with error response ï»¿ï»¿

Tags: web-services, cakephp, nusoap

NUSOAP is generating in the response some rare characters, and when the JSON is bigger it responds an error, like if code was encrypted, in the begining of response shows `ï»¿ï»¿<SOAP-ENV:Envelope...` , i encoded the results as UTF-8, and changed the codification of file to UTF-8 and nothing...

Comment: FYI that is a unicode BOM garbled when treated as text.

Comment: just create a new file with the utf-8 encoding, then paste your code within, then erase the old file with that one

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all.. yes as Alex K said.. it's a BOM character, the problem was not in my file but in an external file, a class file had the character BOM, i noticed using a tool called bomremover.exe which lists the files and batch removes the character. After that all works fine.. the tool was made by  Maurice Wohlkönig